# JQuery/PHP - Ajax Request, JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm trying to do what should be a simple exercise:

Write a number in two inputs, press button, result in the third input.

sum.html:

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Sum</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sum.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input name="a"/>+<input name="b"/>=<input name="c"/>
    <button id="somar"/>SUM</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

sum.php:

```
<?php

    $a = 5; $b = 3;

    function soma($a, $b = 2){
        global $a;
        return $a + $b;
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result" => soma($_GET['a'], $_GET['b'])));
?>
```

sum.js

```
$(document).ready(action);

function action(){
    $("#somar").click(sum);
}

function sum(){
    var a = $("input[name='a']").val();
    var b = $("input[name='b']").val();

    $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          dataType : "json",
          url: "sum.php",  
          data: {"a": a, "b": b}  
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("input[name='c']").val(data.result);
            //alert(0);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert(1);
    });
}
```

The first time I click the button nothing seems to happen and the other times it fails.
Using EasyPHP, I have to close the page and open it again for the same results.

Part of the exercise is predicting the result with the global variable in the middle of php function. I'm only to write the script.

Comment: To begin : `click(sum());`. It's a function not a var.

Comment: To continue: in php function `soma()`, why do you declare `$a` as `global`??? It hides your actual parameter `$a`... :-(

Comment: Thanks Debflav, fixed that, now input c always has the value 5 in it, the sum() seems to run at the start, without clicking. MarcoS, it's part of the code given by the exercise, i'm only to write the script.

Comment: I would expect input c to have value `5 + $b`, for what I said in my previous comment...

Comment: @Debflav When using jquery you don't put the ().. .click(sum) is correct

Comment: @Debflav — Wrong. It is a variable. The variable happens to contain a function. The *function* is being passed as an argument to `click`. By adding `()` you call the function *immediately* and then tell the browser to call `undefined` whenever #somar is clicked.

Comment: @webkit : Ok I didn't know this one. Anyway I think it's better to explicitly put the parentheses. You could have a variable with the same name...

Comment: @Debflav — It is not better to explicitly put the parentheses. That will do something completely different and undesired. You can't have another variable of the same name (at least not in the same scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click your submit button, you are reloading the page and resetting it to the state it was in before the click event fired.

Your `sum` function needs to capture the event object and prevent the default behaviour.

```
function sum(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Yep, why use a form submit at all if using ajax in this case?

Comment: @webkit — Hopefully because of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: This seems to work, but I was under the impression that one of the advantages of this was not having to reload the page to change its content. Is the page reloading because of the ajax request?

Comment: No, the page is reloading because you had a submit button in a form and were clicking it. The default behaviour of a submit button is to submit a form. Submitting forms load new pages.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the answer, Progressive Enhancement some how I understand.. but Unobtrusive Javascript? if you changed the button to an 'a tag' with the same ID, how would that make it obtrusive ?

Comment: @webkit — That would just break progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this code which would prevent it working as expected.

```
$a = 5; $b = 3;
```

should be something like:

```
$a = isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : 0;
$b = isset($_POST['b']) ? $_POST['b'] : 0;
```

Your PHP code is not using values posted from the ajax request. You do not need a global variable

EDIT: Here is some code that I have done which functionally works but does not include the global variable, you can add this in yourself.

```
// test.php
<?php

function sum($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

$a = isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : 0;
$b = isset($_POST['b']) ? $_POST['b'] : 0;

echo json_encode(array('result' => sum($a, $b)));

?>

// test.html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sum</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input name="a"/>+<input name="b"/>=<input name="c"/>
    <button id="somar"/>SUM</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function sum(){
                var a = $("input[name='a']").val();
                var b = $("input[name='b']").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType : "json",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: {"a": a, "b": b}
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $("input[name='c']").val(data.result);
                    //alert(0);
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert(1);
                });
            }

            $("#somar").on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                sum();
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know, but part of the exercise is predicting the result with the global variable in the middle of the exercise. I'm only to write the script.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, I cant see any reason to use a global variable for this?

Comment: I suppose he has been asked to predict results for a given code, as a school exercise...

Comment: There is no reason to use a global variable here, as it will ignore the first input, but part of the exercise is understanding global variables, so it's supposed to be there even though it will only get in the way of an actual sum.

Answer (score 0):

> Tru like this
>   in sum.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sum</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sum.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input name="a"/>+<input name="b"/>=<input name="c"/>
<button id="somar"/>SUM</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

sum.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#somar").click(function() {
                var a = $("input[name='a']").val();
                var b = $("input[name='b']").val();
                //alert(a);
                //alert(b);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'sum.php',
                        data: {"a": a, "b": b},
                        success: function(data) {
                           $("input[name='c']").val(data);
                           //$(".total").prev('input').val("hello world");
                        }
                    });
                });
         });
      </script>
```

in sum.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])){
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
echo $c= $a+$b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You want to add based on user input only then why you pass value to variables in sum.php**

**I made some changes is it okey for you, see the code i changed**

**change in input type in html**

```
<input type="button" id="somar" value="SUM"/>
```

**change your php file**

```
<?php

//$a = 5; $b = 3;

function soma($a, $b ){
    $a= $_GET['a'];
     $b= $_GET['b'];

    return $a + $b;
}

//echo json_encode(array("result" => soma($_GET['a'], $_GET['b'])));
?>
```

**No change in your js file**